# New button next to Edit | Quick Edit | Trash | View

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add a new button at the backend next to Edit | Quick Edit | Trash | View.

I managed to include the button with the following code:

```
    add_filter( 'page_row_actions', 'create_pdf_row_actions', 10, 2 );
function create_pdf_row_actions( $actions, WP_Post $post ) {
    if ( $post->post_type != 'item' ) {
        return $actions;
    }

    $actions['create-pdf'] = '<a href="#" id="pdf">Create PDF</a>';
    return $actions;
}
```

I want an ajax call to test using javascript so that when it is clicked the following is executed:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $("#pdf").click(function(){
          alert("button");
    }); 
  });
```

The problem is that the jquery is running only on the first row. Any idea why?

Comment: Do not use id in `$("#pdf")` use class. also use `on click`

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you!.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#pdf").each(function() {
  $(this).on('click'function(){
    alert("button");
  }); 
});
});
```